# Nutch failing on deleting duplicates (on one solr core but not another)

Tags: apache, hadoop, solr, nutch

I am having a Nutch problem that I cannot seem to debug.

I started using Nutch to crawl and index our page to a solr core 1. And it worked fine. Job completed like it should.

Though I wanted to start indexing or page to our solr core 0, along with other items that we want to index.

The indexing is not the problem, it will crawl and index fine. But on core 0 it continues to fail on the deduplication task at the end of the index. I get the following error (below). From what I can tell, the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml files have all the same things across core0 and core1 except for in core0 the url field is no longer required as the other indexed items don't have a url, so the id field is the standard, required field across all of them. Could it be this that's causing the problem? what is the deduper trying to do and what is getting in its way? and how might I get passed this? thanks!:

`2013-07-26 16:55:17,797 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 157 documents
2013-07-26 16:55:30,407 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2013-07-26 16:55:30,444 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
2013-07-26 16:55:30,444 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2013-07-26 16:55:30,444 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2013-07-26 16:55:30,444 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2013-07-26 16:55:30,444 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2013-07-26 16:55:30,444 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
2013-07-26 16:55:30,444 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: id
2013-07-26 16:55:30,444 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: url
2013-07-26 16:55:31,590 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: finished at 2013-07-26 16:55:31, elapsed: 00:00:19
2013-07-26 16:55:31,593 INFO  solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates - SolrDeleteDuplicates: starting at 2013-07-26 16:55:31
2013-07-26 16:55:31,593 INFO  solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates - SolrDeleteDuplicates: Solr url: http://<domain>:<port>/solr/core0/
2013-07-26 16:55:32,043 WARN  mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Output path is null in cleanup
2013-07-26 16:55:32,043 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1142877999_0055
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.encode(Text.java:388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:178)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates$SolrInputFormat$1.next(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:270)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates$SolrInputFormat$1.next(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documents don't have the url field therefore the id of the documents empty, so its throwing a null pointer exception when it runs the below method.

Below is the code of SolrDeleteDuplicate class  from nutch 1.7 trunk where the solr record is deleted by id field.

```
updateRequest.deleteById(solrRecord.id);
```

- updateRequest => instance of org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.UpdateRequest
- solrRecord => the solr Document which needs to be deleted.
- id => the id of the solr document which is read from the solrindex-mapping.xml present in the conf folder of the nutch distribution. (if this is null then it will throw an exception )

Comment: cool thanks for that explanation. Is there anyway that crawled webpages and non-webpage documents can coexist in the same core when one has a url and one does not?

Comment: on second inspection, it seems like it is deduping the nutch crawled content, and just choking on the non-nutch content, is the error message just kind of incidental? in which case, I don't think I'll do anything further. if it works it works.

Comment: It will dedup only docs which have id field in solr index. For all others, it will throw an exception. To avoid this, don't use url as an id (unique field). Better use a  [signature](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication) field as the id.